# Products are not visible at frontend Magento 2

Tags: frontend, products, catalogsearch, category-products, indexer

There's two created product each of them is set:
Product Type : Simple

- Website : Main Websites
- Status : Enabled
- Visibility: Catalog, Search
- Salable Quantity: >50
  I use Magento 2.4.4 Open source installed on localhost through Xampp at Windows PC.
  It is a bit strange that left column containing filters show the values of mentioned products (their prices), but the products are not visible.
  I've tried several times to flush the cache, reindexing, deploy again the static content but nothing works.
  I couldn't find solution in any of the reported issues in many forums (maybe my case is a bit differente.
  [image]

Please good people give me your suggestion what i can do to solve it. If i missed any required information please share with me and i will provide it.

Comment: check css or disable third party theme or disable third party extensions and check any console errors

Comment: CSS is not modified and seems to be deployed properly (it is in state that comes from base installation of magento). Console does not show any errors (make the check both in Chrome and Edge browsers). I am not sure about third party theme (there's only Luma and Blank available). Regard Third party extensions i did not install anything - if basic installation comes with third party extensions how to found them and check if they are the issue. - Than you for your answer Niraj :)

Comment: Do you got any exception?

Comment: Actually Console returns this an issue now: jquery-migrate.js:69 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version  (but even didn't highlight it neither yellow or red). It is just state 1 issue and that is.

Comment: Sometimes when you reindex everything it will show no errors, but there might be error in `var/log/exception.log`. In my case I needed to add `indices.id_field_data.enabled: true` in elastic configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Please check elasticsearch status.

```
service elasticsearch status
service elasticsearch start
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: Hello Priya, thank you for your answer. 

I check elastic search - from Magento admin panel (Configuration -> Catalog - Catalog search) - it return "Succesfull! Try Again". Additional i check localhost:9020 - and report that elastic search is running. I run elastic search through Windows CMD as administrator and it's left to working in background.
- Not sure how when to place to command you provide : "service elasticsearch status" & "service elasticsearch start"

I run both commands php bin/magento - but nothing improve.
This is not the solution for my issue i guess :(.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Please run below commands

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset && php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

That's it. Check Your Products now.

Thanks,

Comment: Hello Sonal, thanks for your answer. Run both commands (succesfully) it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be elasticsearch is not running on your local system.

If you are using the windows PC then follow the below steps.

1. Go to the Windows command prompt.
2. Go to the installation folder where you have unzipped the Elasticsearch file.
3. Run “bin\elasticsearch.bat”.
4. Elasticsearch has now started and the window should remain open.
5. Now go to the magento root directory and run the indexer command

> ```
>  php bin/magento indexer:reset
>
>  php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
>  php bin/magento c:f
> ```

Thanks

Comment: Hello Vikas, thank you for your answer. Elasticsearch is up and running this is the second thing i always do and check before running Xampp and start localhost. Both through Magento Admin Panel (Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog search - testconnection) - return "Successfull!Try again" and in browser localhost:9020 - return that elasticsearch is on. Elastich search is located at same folder as magento installation is. Thank you once again, but seems like my issue is not solvalbe by the solution.

Comment: products is not showing only on category listing pages or it is not showing even search and directly open the product page by their url key?

Comment: the products are not shown neither at listing, search or their respective urls.

Answer (score 0):

- Enable developer mode
- Compile, run index and clear cache
- Open the product listing/ category page
- Access your backend and remove all generated logs
- Make sure you selected inbuilt cache or disabled the cache in
  magento backend
- Refresh your product page
- Check all the generated log files, there you can find out what
  might be the issue
- Make sure you selected inbuilt cache or disabled the cache in magento
  backend